# VHDL: formal generic 'n' has no actual or default value?

Tags: vhdl, vivado

I'm trying to simulate my VHDL component in Vivado and i'm receiving a compilation error: "formal generic 'n' has no actual or default value". I would appreciate any advice or solution to this error.

I have seen the issue [VHDL: formal port 'portName' has no actual or default value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57639047/vhdl-formal-port-portname-has-no-actual-or-default-value) and my error, although similar, does not seem related.

```
entity bit_tester is 
generic (N : integer);
port(in1 : in bit_vector (N-1 downto 0);
    out1 : out bit;
    out2 :out bit;
    out3 :out bit);
end bit_tester;

architecture behavioral of bit_tester is
```

Comment: *...and my error, although similar, does not seem related.* Prithee how does your error differ that's it not related?  See [ask], provide a [mcve]. A generic constant either has an assigned value (in a generic map), has a default value or produces an error. Some simulators can supply generics values as command line arguments.

Comment: You need to show the relevant code.   In this case it is also the instance of entity bit_tester.  At that point, you did not give the generic a value.    Do a google search on mapping VHDL generics.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from the question how you are trying to simulate this entity.

But you are not providing a value for your generic "N"

You have to either assign it a default value:

```
entity bit_tester is 
generic (N : integer := 5);
port(in1 : in bit_vector (N-1 downto 0);
    out1 : out bit;
    out2 :out bit;
    out3 :out bit);
end bit_tester;
```

Or give it a value when you instantiate the entity:

```
inst_bit_tester:bit_tester
generic map(N => 5)
port map(in1 => in1,
    out1 => out1,
    out2 => out2,
    out3 => out3);
```